# To what extent should programming-related questions be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This might be a big issue that we have to resolve before getting out of private/public beta: How programming-related can questions on Vim.SE be?

For example, questions about using Vim as a programming tool are probably on-topic. How about programming in Vimscript? What about questions that require a few lines of Vimscript, but are not purely focused on the programming aspect (ex. How can I do <task that requires 5-line script>)?

What other code-related questions are on- and off-topic?

Comment: for example, the following question: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/474/making-a-box-in-vim-via-python

Answer (score 6):

I would say that Vimscript is on-topic. It's a Vim feature. This site is about Vim.

Of course, the general rules of on- and off-topic apply. "plz give codez fast. kthxbye' is obviously off-topic.

Vim can also interface with Ruby, Python, Lua, and some other languages (if compiled as such). Those questions would be on-topic if it's about programming the Vim editor (ie. someone making a plugin, having a problem):

- An on-topic example might be someone trying to make Vim do *x* through Python, but failing because Vim does *y*. This is obviously about Vim's Python interface.
- An off-topic example might be someone with a question on how to properly use *[python language feature foo]*. He or she might be using the Vim Python API, but the question isn't *about* it, as such.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to express how I feel it (to hopefully open some discussion if I happen to be controversial)

**Vi(m) is a text editor.** Yes, it can serve as a fairly good operating system (similarly as the editor-whose-name-is-forbidden-here can), but it's not at all its purpose. So as long as the question is about writing a script that really helps in editing a file, it is IMHO ok, for instance something like (sorry it's stoopid):

> Scripting Vim to convert an HTML table to the LaTeX syntax

However, some questions are about Vi(m) but certainly not about Vi(m) as an editor, for instance:

> How to write a prime tester in VimScript?

---

As a note, I'd like to say that conceptual questions about Vim as a programming language should be fine as well, even though they don't help to edit files in Vim.